# Error Launching Android Studio Failed to Create JVM error code -1

Tags: java, android, jvm

[I even uninstall android studio and java multiple times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2I8a5.png)

[i also checked multiple times environment variables but issue sill persist it waste my lot of time.][2]

[Java version check , java environment is completely setup, Android studio gives error for JVM might possible it cached Any help?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZfcE.png)

Comment: i implemented multiple solutions from stack over flow but no success.

Comment: Have you defined JAVA_HOME look at the link for setting up JAVA_HOME https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/820-7851/inst_cli_jdk_javahome_t/

Comment: yes i defined JAVA_HOME variable i attached image at above link.

Comment: you can lookup output images.

Comment: Have you got the right version of JDK. ie you are running x86 machine and by mistake download x64?

Comment: Now i deleted all old directories for android studio placed in C:\Users\myuser\.android*

Comment: yes i downloaded it from https://www.oracle.com it works for multiple compilers such as intelliJ

Comment: did you get the correct version that matches your operating system? Windows x86 jdk-8u121-windows-i586.exe
Windows x64 jdk-8u121-windows-x64.exe

Comment: yes it matches to OS as it is 64 bit

Comment: it i'm using java on same machine for other Applications

Comment: Is it possible that due update this issue came as i think android studio was in update then in between progress it canceled it and then i run android studio i got these kinds of error then i reinstall java.

Comment: @asim-dogar, Consider asking such questions on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: @LuFFy i'm new here can please guide me about it

Comment: okay it is for quick response

Comment: Thanks all, after deleting those directories(C:\Users\myuser\.android*) and then reinstall android studio it is working fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete :directories(C:\Users\myuser.android*) 
and then reinstall android studio it is working fine now.

Comment: thanks man you solved my problem , you are at least better then those meatheads who skipped this question by saying "it is too broad.."